# IF Else variable issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue  with two of my IF ELSE statements erroring out but not a third.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in employees2.php on line 51 
0 results

```
// Pass appropriate SQL to the database
$lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lname"]);
$fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["fname"]);
$empid = htmlspecialchars($_POST["empid"]);

echo "<h3>Search results.</h3>";
$sqlL = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LAST_NAME = \"" . $lname . "\"";
$sqlF = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE FIRST_NAME \"" . $fname . "\"";
$sqlID = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID \"" . $empid . "\""; 
$resultL = $conn->query($sqlL);
$resultF = $conn->query($sqlF);
$resultID = $conn->query($sqlID);

if ($resultF->num_rows > 0) {
    // Output data of each row
    printf("\n\t<table><th>Name</th>
                       <th>Employee ID</th>
           ");
    while ($row = $resultF->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf("\n\t<tr><td>%s%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td></tr>", 
               $row["LAST_NAME"], $row["FIRST_NAME"], $row["EMPLOYEE_ID"]);
    }

    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "<h5><strong>($resultF->num_rows) results returned.</strong></h5><br>";
} else {
    echo "0 results ";
}
```

Comment: You are missing your `=` in your `$sqlF` && `$sqlID` queries -> `...WHERE FIRST_NAME  \"" . $fname . "\"";`/`...WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID  \"" . $empid . "\"";`. So your queries fail, so your `$resultF` and `$resultID` will result in `non-object`s

Answer (score 0):

try `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultF))`

Comment: How would changing from OOP to Procedural style fix the OPs issue?

Comment: Does not work. Now I get a **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object** error.

Comment: I'm an extreme noob. Researching as I go.

Comment: @JohnChaney have you tried adding the missing `=` in your 2 queries that I mentioned in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401546/if-else-variable-issue#comment58505227_35401546) 29 mins ago? Your queries have invalid syntax, so they are failing, causing the `non-object` messages.

Comment: Ok, call  me thick, but I don't see where I'm missing the =.

Comment: look at `$sqlF = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE FIRST_NAME \"" . $fname . "\"";`. This will result in `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE FIRST_NAME "John";`. Where it should be `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE FIRST_NAME = "John";`. You need a `=` between your column name and value in your `WHERE` condition in both `$sqlF` and `$sqlID`. If you look at `$sqlL = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LAST_NAME = \"" . $lname . "\"";` you should see a `=` between `LAST_NAME` and `\"" . $lname . "\"";` which produces a valid `LAST_NAME = "Chaney"`.